# How to fix '[Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path '/' in Laravel Vue.js project?

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, laravel-10, vue-router4

using laravel and vue 3  face this [Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/"

Hi I am facing this error in console **[Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/**"
using vue router 4 and laravel
it is my **routes.js** code

```
import {createRouter, createWebHistory}  from 'vue-router';
import testcomponent from './testcomponent.vue';


const routes = [

    {
        path: "/test",
        name: "test",
        component : testcomponent,
    },

];

const router = createRouter({
    history:createWebHistory(),
    routes
});

export default router;
```

it is my **App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="nav">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light navbar-light">
      <router-link class="navbar-brand" v-bind:to="{name:'test'}">test</router-link> 
      
    </nav>
  </div>
  <router-view />
</template>
```

it is **web.php** code

```
Route::get('/{any?}', function () {
    return view('vuecheck');
})->where('any', '^(?!api\/)[\/\w\.\,-]*');
```

when i call this route **http://127.0.0.1:8000/** facing this issue in console

Comment: any answer would be recommended

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably a little late for this but that warning means that you don't have a route defined in your file for the path: `/` so you need to add that to your routes array in your routes file, something like:

```js
const routes = [
    {
        path: "/",
        name: "home", // or any name you want
        component: [Home Component], //You need to crate and import this component
    },
    {
        path: "/test",
        name: "test",
        component : testcomponent,
    },

];
```